# Filter multiple items from the output of a long running command

Tags: bash, terminal, pipe, dialog, handbrake

**TLDR:**

How do I run handbrakecli, get progress **and** ETA, pipe into dialog without flickering.

**Details:**

I have a script that finds all video files in a directory and then runs handbrakecli on them one at a time. Everytime handbrakecli runs it spits out a bunch of information about the file etc. and then the line:

```
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 3.30 % (295.53 fps, avg 303.23 fps, ETA 00h02m54s)
```

In my script I pipe the handbrakecli command to some other commands to filter out everything except the progress and then I pipe that to dialog like so:

**Snippet 1**

```
HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$f" -o "$DEST" | \
    stdbuf -o0 tr -s '\r' '\n' | \
    stdbuf -o0 grep -oP '(?<=, )\d+(?=\.\d\d \%)' | \
    dialog --gauge "$DIALOG_MSG" 10 70;
```

This works fine. It shows the progress and it doesn't flicker. Second task was to come up with a way to show both the progress AND the ETA and this is what I came up with:

**Snippet 2**

```
HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$f" -o "$DEST_FULL_FILE" | \
    stdbuf -oL tr -s '\r' '\n' | \
    while read -r str; do
        local REMAINING=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=ETA )\d\dh\d\dm\d\ds(?=\))");
        local PROGRESS=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=, )\d+(?=.\d\d)");
        echo "$PROGRESS" | dialog --gauge "$DIALOG_MSG Time remaining: $REMAINING" 10 70;
    done
```

This works but the dialog window flickers. I don't know if it's performance related (doubt it) or if the whole *while read* loop just doesn't work well with dialog.

I also tried doing it without piping to dialog but that just showed dialog once and then didn't update it at all.

**Snippet 3**

```
HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$f" -o "$DEST_FULL_FILE" | \
    stdbuf -oL tr -s '\r' '\n' | \
    while read -r str; do
        local REMAINING=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=ETA )\d\dh\d\dm\d\ds(?=\))");
        local PROGRESS=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=, )\d+(?=.\d\d)");
        dialog --gauge "$DIALOG_MSG Time remaining: $REMAINING" 10 70 $PROGRESS;
    done
```

Finally I tried this:

**Snippet 4**

```
HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$f" -o "$DEST_FULL_FILE" | \
    stdbuf -o0 tr -s '\r' '\n' | (
        read -r str;                                                                                                                          
        local REMAINING=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=ETA )\d\dh\d\dm\d\ds(?=\))");
        local PROGRESS=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=, )\d+(?=.\d\d)");
        echo "$PROGRESS";
    ) | dialog --gauge "$DIALOG_MSG Time remaining: $REMAINING" 10 70;
```

And that didn't work out well at all.

I'm aware there are some fundamental things wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet 2 is closest. `dialog --gauge` will optionally look for the magic marker `XXX` in the input and then read the new percentage from the following line, and the new prompt from the lines after that until a new marker.

So you should get what you want with:

```
HandBrakeCLI --preset "Normal" -i "$f" -o "$DEST_FULL_FILE" |
stdbuf -oL tr -s '\r' '\n' |
while read -r str
do
    REMAINING=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=ETA )\d\dh\d\dm\d\ds(?=\))")
    PROGRESS=$(echo "$str" | grep -oP "(?<=, )\d+(?=.\d\d)")
    echo -e "XXX\n$PROGRESS\n$DIALOG_MSG Time remaining: $REMAINING\nXXX"
done | 
dialog --gauge "$DIALOG_MSG Time remaining: " 10 70;
```